# Why this usage string with ostream cause stackoverflow?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stack-overflow, ostream

I just wondering why this code is incorrect ? It constantly call Foo constructor and cause stack overflow after sometime.

```cpp
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class Foo
    {
        std::string str;
    public:
        Foo(const string& s) : str(s)
        {
            cout << "Foo constructor" << endl;
        }  
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,const Foo& foo);
    };

    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,const Foo& foo)
    {
        os << foo.str;
        return os;
    }

    int main()
    { 
        Foo foo{"Hello"};   
        cout << foo;    
        cin.get();
    }
```

I know, I know it is ok to write

`cout << foo.str << endl;`

or `os << foo.str.c_str();`

but I want to know why this error happens..

Comment: It looks fine. The problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe this is Visual C++ bug ?

Comment: Or something weird going into `cin.get()`, which you should probably remove.

Comment: Can you make `Foo`'s construct `explicit` and see if the problem still exists?

Comment: @DietmarKühl - this cause compile error - no operator '<<' matches these operands (if I apply explicit to Foo constructor).

Comment: @juanchopanza - no its not the case for this error

Comment: @ChaosDev: good - at least, we now know that the problem is `os << foo.str` is turned into `os << Foo(foo.str)` explaining the infinite recursion. The next question becomes *why* that is the case! Try including `#include <string>`: it seems the definition of `std::string` is available but possibly not all declarations from the `<string>` header.

Comment: @DietmarKühl - Yeah, you right - this fixed this issue. Thank you..

Comment: Ok, that much for static typing...

Comment: A very interesting bug. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program use `std::string` and its output operator but does **not** include the header `<string>`: when using `<string>` you need to include that header. The fact that `std::string` seems to be defined by including `<iostream>` is insufficient. It is also not portable: a different implementation may choose to only declare but not defined `std::string` (a declaration is needed, though, as some IOStream members to use the type `std::string`).

If the output operator for `std::string` isn't found, the expression

```
out << foo.str
```

is interpreted as as

```
out << Foo(foo.str)
```

as there *is* an output operator for `Foo`. Of course, that does result in an infinite recursion.

Comment: So the iostream include string just as forward declaration and correct conversion to ostream exist in <string> header ?

Comment: @ChaosDev: I don't have MSVC++ accessible so I don't know what they do exactly. It _seems_ as if including `<iostream>` does _define_ `std::string` (otherwise you wouldn't be able to create a member of this type) but does not provide all declarations from the header `<string>`. Notably, it seems including `<iostream>` does **not** provide a declaration of `std::string`'s output operator while `<string>` does provide this operator.